# Running out of memory (512MB) with image helper

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.12

I'm having a strange problem where the following *single* operation causes an out-of-memory problem (limit at 512MB) when the following conditions are met:

1. `$product` is a configurable product with no image. (placeholder/fallback image is available)
2. `$product` has no simple products associated.
3. `$this->helper...->resize(135)` is assigned to a variable (no problem when simply `echo`ed in HTML).

Following is the code:

```
$variable = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(135)
```

I tried casting it as a `string` and that relieves the problem and memory usage is not abnormal. Below...

```
$variable = (string)$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(135)
```

Any idea what's happening?

Additional info:

nginx error.log shows `PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 501481472 bytes)...` (***!***this seems very abnormal to me. It's trying to allocate ~500MB on just that one call?)

Placeholder image is available.

Comment: It might help (or might not) to see where the process is when PHP runs out of memory (i.e. copy/paste the exact error message)

Comment: Hm, our nginx `error.log` shows only `PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 501481472 bytes)...`. Where can I find a more detailed log?

Comment: Do you have a fallback image in place? This can be set under `System > Configuration > Catalog`

Comment: @Sander, yeah it's available. When I cast `string`, it returns the placeholder image.

Comment: Is it a specific image that it crashes on? And if so what's the image file type?

Comment: Nope. The placeholder image is just the default grey Magento image. If you look at the PHP error message, it's trying to allocate a large amount of memory for something that returns just a string.

Comment: Does it work when you bump the memory up to 1024?

Comment: @youn set the PHP `error_log` ini to temporarily log errors to a separate file.  It seems PHP or nginx cut off the error message text — at minimum you should get a file with a line number that tells where PHP hit the memory limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory errors can be tricky to track down, and are almost always system specific (that's a fancy way of saying "I don't have a specific solution for you, but here's some debugging tips).

Memory problems usually happen for one of two reasons.

1. Repeated loading of something in a loop without clearing memory from the previous loop
2. Loading something too large

Based on your error message

> Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 501481472 bytes).

It sounds like you have PHP's memory limit set to 536870912 bytes (`512MB`), and PHP ran into a problem when it attempted to allocate `501481472` bytes.  That is, in a single operation, PHP attempted to set aside around [478MB of memory](https://www.google.com/search?q=501481472+bytes+in+MB) to hold the image helper object you attempted to put in a variable.  (`resize` returns `$this`, meaning a copy of the image helper)

```
$variable = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(135)
```

My guess is your base images are **huge** files, and that one the objects used by the image helper had that image loaded in memory.  When cast that object as a string (which for an image helper returns the images URL, see its `__toString` method.

```
$variable = (string)$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(135)
```

PHP didn't need to keep a copy of this around.

That, however, is just a guess.  I'd up the memory limit temporarily to `1024MB` to see if that clears up the problem.  If it doesn't, that means you have a runaway loop loading too many things.  If it does clear the problem up, takes steps to up PHP's memory limit **only when this operation needs to run**.