# Difference between $this->helper('catalog/image')->... vs. (string)$this->helper('catalog/image')->

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.12

Can someone explain how the image helper works in Magento and if the following two lines are identical? They appear to be identical strings when I run `var_dump($temp)`, but memory usage says otherwise on certain products (outside of the scope of this question, but it happens on certain products and casting the `string` alleviates the problem).

```
$temp = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(135);

$temp = (string)$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(135);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those 2 lines are not identical.
After the first line `$temp` will be an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`. This is because the `resize` method returns the currend object.

After the second line `$temp` will be a string.
When casting an object to a string it's the same as calling `$object->__toString();`
You can take a look at the `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::__toString()` methods. This is the one that actually creates the cached, resized image if it doesn't exist and returns the url of the image.

About the memory usage, I cant say much. What are you doing with `$temp` after the lines above? Maybe you do something that reaches the memory limit.

Comment: Ah, does `__toStrign()` work the same for string-casting inside PHP and when `echo`ing in HTML?

Comment: Regarding the memory usage, simply assigning `$this->helper()->...` to a variable allocates ~500MB of memory on **certain** products. I have a post here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/running-out-of-memory-512mb-with-image-helper. But I do need to run some more tests to cases.

Comment: when calling `echo` on an object PHP tries to convert it to string so it calls the same `__toString` method.

Comment: Now I remember about the magic function.. I seem to regularly forget about this. Def need to use need to use OOP more. I see it in Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image where it returns the string URL.

Comment: if you have to manipulate the url of the cached resized image, like doing a substr match and editing the url, it will be more efficient to cast the helper image object to string. Otherwise every time that substr is called on the object a __toString() is called, which affects performance quite a bit if you do it often.